# Want to find difference between two frames, but get a lot of noise because of the auto changing on exposure, brightness...(not sure) of the webcam

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

As title, I tried to use Raspberry Pi + logitech webcam to find the difference between two frames, the following is the code that I used:

```
import cv2


#capture from camera at location 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    #cv2.imshow("input", img)

    ...

    framediff = cv2.absdiff(Previousframe, frame)

    ...

    cv2.imshow("frame", framediff)

    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break


cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
cv2.VideoCapture(0).release()
```

When there are some moving objects pass through, the webcam will auto change "
Focus", "Brightness", "Exposure"...I am not sure... and I will see a lot of noise in framediff, so I think I need to change some setting of my webcam to reduce this kind of noise, I saw someone post about cap.set(), but not sure which setting I need to change, also change to what value... does anyone have this kind of experiences?

Comment: try histogram equalization on each channel

Comment: Try to use the H-channel after converting BGR2HSV